# What controls the appearance of the "Web" option in the spring boot administrator UI?

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I'm having an issue with using Spring Boot Administrator against a number of different Spring Boot microservices, where the *Web* left-hand menu option (which has the *Mappings* and *HTTP Traces* suboptions) only shows for some of the microservices.

The only obvious POM differences between those microservices that work and those that don't is the Spring Boot Starter parent version; those which display the *Web* option are using version `2.1.6.RELEASE`, while those that do not are using higher versions like `2.3.1.RELEASE` (which I'm guessing will affect versions of e.g. spring boot actuator libraries).

I'm using version 2.3.0 of Spring Boot Admin Server with Spring Boot Starter Parent 2.3.1.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that stumbled upon this, the answer is that from Spring Boot 2.0.0 onwards, in order to expose the Spring Boot actuator httptrace endpoint (which is what drives the *Web* option in the Spring Boot Administrator), you now need to also add a bean that implements `HttpTraceRepository` into your Spring context.

e.g.

```
@Configuration
public class HttpTraceActuatorConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public HttpTraceRepository httpTraceRepository() {
    return new InMemoryHttpTraceRepository();
  }
}
```